# How to offset from a local variable using x64 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I'm trying to access a second local variable on the current stack frame, located at (I think?) `%rsp-8`, since the first is located at `%rsp`. What I'd like to do is load the address at `%rsp-8` into another register. Note that this means the address that's currently stored *at* `rsp`, and not the data *at that* address in memory. Is it possible to do this without having to declare a separate register that stores the offset (or increments the current `rsp`)?

What I currently have:

```
...
    movq %rsp, %rsi             # Move the first address at rsp into rsi.
    leaq infmt, %rdi            # Load the input format string into rdi.
    movq $0, %rax               # Clear rax since it is a var-args procedure.
    call scanf
    movq %rsp, %rbx
    addq $8, %rbx
    movq %rbx, %rsi            # Move the next address at rsp into rsi.
    leaq infmt, %rdi           # Reload the input format.
    call scanf
...
```

What would be *nice* to have:

```
...
    movq %rsp, %rsi             # Move the first address at rsp into rsi.
    leaq infmt, %rdi            # Load the input format string into rdi.
    movq $0, %rax               # Clear rax since it is a var-args procedure.
    call scanf
    movq %rbx-8, %rsi           # Move the next address at rsp into rsi.
    leaq infmt, %rdi            # Reload the input format.
    call scanf
...
```

Comment: Use LEA with a register addressing mode; that's what it's for.   But note that passing an address below the current RSP isn't going to work well before a `call`; you'll be asking scanf to overwrite its own return address!  Also, the LEAs for the format string should be RIP-relative, `lea infmt(%rip), %rdi`.  [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a value to a register with `leaq` using a displacement. Instead of this:

```
movq %rsp, %rbx
addq $8, %rbx
movq %rbx, %rsi
```

you can do this:

```
leaq 8(%rsp), %rsi
```

While this looks like a register dereference that would normally be used with `movq`, with `leaq` it just uses the value of `%rsp` and adds the displacement.

This can also be used with negative values, e.g. `-8(%rsp)` since you mentioned you needed `%rsp-8`.